# ActiveRecord and non-blocking Postgres

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, nonblocking, eventmachine, grape-api

I'm wanting to use Grape, Goliath and ActiveRecord to build a non-blocking API in Ruby. The problem I'm running into is there seems to be nothing happening on the EM/Postgres async front. Any activity seems to have stopped around 2012. The only thing I've found is the [ruby-em-pg-client](https://github.com/royaltm/ruby-em-pg-client) but that specifically states it does not support ActiveRecord and hasn't had any activity in 8 months. The [Grape/Goliath example](https://github.com/djones/grape-goliath-example) provided by djones is using an EM Postgres adapter that hasn't be modified since 2012.

I'm hoping that maybe the pg gem has async built in which negates the need for something special but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not. I've been looking more towards the Node.js front when it comes to async these days.